# Airflow 2 - debugging why dag is not loading

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

On Airflow 2 my dag is not showing on the UI, and I'm getting **DAG Import Errors (...)** for it.
The error message is insufficient for me to debug (it's a custom operator, with a lot of custom logic - so I don't want to get into details of the error itself).
On Airflow 1.X I could use cli:

```sh
airflow list_dags
```

to get more elaborated debug message, is there anything analogical on airflow 2 ?
I'm looking for a cli command/UI option that will provide me with more elaborated error message, than the one I'm getting on the main screen of the webserver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [Airlfow's documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html?highlight=testing#dag-loader-test), to test DAG loading you can simply run:

```
python your-dag-file.py
```

If there is any problem during the DAG loading phase you will get a stack trace here.

The [later sections](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html?highlight=testing#unit-tests) also describe how to test custom operators.

Comment: Thanks, that's the good and universal one.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [upgrading manual](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/upgrading-to-2.html#airflow-cli-changes-in-2-0) the
`airflow list_dags` has been changed to `airflow dags list`

The full syntax is:

```
airflow dags list [-h] [-o table, json, yaml] [-S SUBDIR]
```

for more information see [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#list_repeat2)

Comment: I see it's written like this, however it's definitely not the case in terms of logs - try it yourself - airflow 2 version provides literally a list only, whereas airflow 1 was providing pretty extensive logs.

Comment: please open a github issue https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues with examples and we will look into it